# jquery display img on different div depending on where it was clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, prepend

To better explain what I need I uploaded an example [here](http://bellotaestudio.com/test/acabados.php).

I have 3 divs, and clicking on either one of them will have the same image menu appear on the right.  What I have now is: click on the first div, then go to the menu, choose an image and use `.prepend()` to show that image on the clicked div.  But if I get the image menu appearing when clicking the second or third div and choose a color, this is still displayed on the first div.

A simplified HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="tela1"><img src="img/blank.jpg" /></div>
<div id="title_tela1"></div>
<div id="tela2"><img src="img/blank.jpg" /></div>
<div id="title_tela2"></div>

<div id="tela1_options">
    <div class="image_carousel1>
        Content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tela2_options">
    <div class="image_carousel2>
        Content goes here...
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.carousel_image1 img').click(function () {
    var imageName = $(this).attr('alt');
    var chopped = imageName.split('.');
    $('#title_tela1').empty();
    $('#title_tela1')
        .prepend(chopped[0]);
    $img = $(this);
    $('#tela1 img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
})
```

I tried using the selector `('#tela1_options .carousel_image1 img')` for each of the three divs, but still when I choose an image is displayed only on the first div.

Can someone take a look and help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of you click function for the carousel, you have "#tela1" hard coded.  That part needs to be dynamic based on what div was clicked.  You will probably want to store the clicked div in a variable that will be used inside of the click function.  Here is a sample of what your document.ready function could look like:

```
$(function(){
    var clickedDiv = null;

    $(".tela").click(function(){
        clickedDiv = $(this);
    });

    $('.carousel_image1 img').click(function () {
        var $img = $(this),
            imageName = $img.attr('alt'),
            chopped = imageName.split('.');

        clickedDiv.next().text(chopped[0]);
        clickedDiv.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
    });
});
```

In order for that to work, you will need to add the class="tela" to the divs.

```
<div id="tela1" class="tela"><img src="img/blank.jpg" /></div>
<div id="title_tela1"></div>
<div id="tela2" class="tela"><img src="img/blank.jpg" /></div>
<div id="title_tela2"></div>
```

Here is a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jY4qa/2/
I only set up the images in the first carousel to show up.  But if you click on one of the blank divs and then an image it sets it correctly.  I also had to update the image carousel selector in the JS for my example.